# Update static after AXIOS? VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, axios

I have some problems with vue:

i have a list of elements

> v-for(item in array)

this array i get from Axios (from API) in

> created(){}

part of my script. In my template, i have a static variable.

> {{colors.green[this.number]}}

And! This static var is not appear after rendering a template (after axios.post).
So, i think, i need to update this var or DOM. Or may be there is another way.. What do you think about it? Thank you!

UPDATE. Still cant solve it

[Params](https://prnt.sc/k4ai1o)

[List](http://prntscr.com/k4aj1w)

[DOM](https://prnt.sc/k4ahd4)

Comment: Can you show a more detailed code?

Comment: Yes, still cant solve this. 
http://prntscr.com/k4ahd4
http://prntscr.com/k4ai1o

Answer (score 1):

You can't use outside variables in your templates, if you need to use global variable into your template, you would need to wrap it in a `data` variable.

```
{
    data: function(){
        return {
            colors: colors
        };
    }
}
```

and after that, it should render now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Used a function:

[DOM](http://prntscr.com/k4ar2u)

[Function](http://prntscr.com/k4arfw)

Comment: Take note, component methods aren't reactive.